# HHVM/FastCGI/Proxy installation ruin my apache?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, proxy, hhvm

I have a ubuntu 14.04 laptop installed apache2 and php5. they both work well. Yesterday I got a spare time and gave it a try to install nginx and hhvm. I followed some tutorial on internet and managed to install them. but when I need to use apache again, it didn't work. actually when I open http://localhost, it still display 'Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page' page but it can't process any php file even a page with phpinfo() function. I remember after installing hhvm, I executed this:

```
sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh
```

Here is the output:

```
Checking if Apache is installed
Detected Apache installation
Looking for custom proxy configuration
No custom proxy configuration found
Checking for enabled proxy_fcgi.load
Not found
Checking for enabled fastcgi.load
Not found
Checking for enabled fcgid.load
Not found
Checking for available proxy_fcgi.load
Found, checking for loading directives
Detected available proxy_fcgi.load configuration, setting up integration
Checking for available hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf
Found, checking for loading directives
Detected available hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf configuration, setting up integration
Checking for available proxy.load
Found, checking for loading directives
Detected available proxy.load configuration, setting up integration
Checking for available proxy.conf
Found, checking for loading directives
Detected available proxy.conf configuration, setting up integration
Enabling module proxy.load
Found available module
Creating a symlink
Finished creating a symlink
Enabling module proxy.conf
Found available module
Creating a symlink
Finished creating a symlink
Enabling module proxy_fcgi.load
Found available module
Creating a symlink
Finished creating a symlink
Force enabling module hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf
Available module found
Removed possible duplicates
Enabling module hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf
Found available module
Creating a symlink
Finished creating a symlink
Completed force enabling
Restarting apache
Finished restarting apache
Checking if Nginx is installed
Detected Nginx installation
Checking for custom Nginx configuration
Enabling hhvm Nginx module
Finished enabling module
Restarting Nginx
Nginx is running, restarting
Restarted nginx
Finished restarting Nginx
```

I suspect that line ruin my apache. I don't know how to revert it back. is there any way to do it? i dont want to use fastcgi or any proxy and i want to deactivate/remove them.
I got this error 'Internal Server Error' on my browser when any php file is processed. from apache error log, I got this:

```
[Wed Mar 02 15:12:13.519428 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 20485] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Wed Mar 02 15:12:13.519509 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 20485] [client 127.0.0.1:54656] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

Then I disable proxy_fcgi

```
sudo a2dismod proxy_fcgi
```

Now I got this error in apache error log:

```
[Wed Mar 02 15:44:41.946487 2016] [proxy:warn] [pid 21422] [client 127.0.0.1:55563] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /info.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I dont know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

From this link: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3472, The culprit is this file:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/hhvm_proxy_fcgi.conf.
```

Because i dont have time to play more, the quick solution is just rename/remove the file. Now My Apache server is working again.